# Is it possible to use JOOQ to form a simple string query without creating factory using connection as compile time check is not required?

Tags: mysql, jooq

Is it possible to use JOOQ to form a simple string query without creating factory using connection as compile time check is not required?

I dont want to establish the connection first and generate the classes

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can execute SQL as strings. But you will loose all benefits from code completion will writing queries and the type safety and this is the many advantage of jOOQ over using plain JDBC.

```
// Create a Query object and execute it:
Query query = create.query("DELETE FROM BOOK");
query.execute();

// Create a ResultQuery object and execute it, fetching results:
ResultQuery<Record> resultQuery = create.resultQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOK");
Result<Record> result = resultQuery.fetch();
```

Please also checkout the documentation. https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual-single-page/#sql-execution